# Kind of configuration settings can be made in XML files (web.config)?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, configuration, configuration-files

As we know there are some config setting we can make to web.config file like mentioned at [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/sahannet/archive/2008/02/13/asp-net-web-config-file.aspx)

Now as a beginner i need to know what else we can do with this file/ i.e what else we can configure with this file in ASP.NET MVC2,3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure many other items in the web.config.  However this question is not direct enough to provide an answer.

You can see the entire schema [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5ysx397%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Mantorok that's what i am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Web.Config is not limited to any application. Web.config can work verymuch in same way for any applications. Along with the mentioned details we can include a bunch of sections into Web.Config. some of them includes

1) If you are using any services, then service end points you can define in web.config.

2) Error/Exception handling configuraton you can define.

3) if you will use Unity, you can define Register types in config.

4) Any IIS configuratons, can overridden in web.config.

5) Any IIS Error page setup.